# Hide parts of three.js mesh using alphaMap in material

Tags: javascript, three.js

We want to hide parts of a mesh. At the moment we try this using the alphaMap property on the material. Unfortunately this doesn't affect the mesh at all. The used code is:

```
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        ambient: 0xBABABA,
        color: 0xBABABA,
        specular: 0xA1A1A1,
        shininess: 10,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
        reflectivity: 0.20,
        envMap: cubemap,
        bumpScale: 0.15,
        // alphaMap
        alphaMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/TransparentMap.png"),
        transparent: true,
})
```

We also tryed multiple alphaMaps including: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2yHD.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIvyc.png) one.

If there is a better solution for hiding parts of a mesh beside from alphaMap we are also always open for it.

Comment: What version of the library are you using?

Comment: I am using version 67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `alphaMap` property was added in version r.68. You need to upgrade.

If at all possible, always use the current version.

Also, the alpha map should be a grayscale map. Only the green channel of that map is read, however.

three.js r.69